# OpenCart 4 API calls in PHP

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to use OpenCart 4 API in PHP but I can't figure out how to get a token properly and how to make API calls. The documentation is written in Python, so I'm not even able to get a token for authentication.

I managed to get a token for earlier versions using the below code:

```
$post = [
    'username' => 'Username',
    'key' => 'key',
];

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/index.php?route=api/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $response;

?>
```

But after I get the token I don't know how to do the actual calls to get the orders and other stuff because there is no documentation for PHP.

In the new version (4.0.0.0) this code gets me an HTML response with a not found page. So does anyone know how to do proper calls in php in the new or old versions. It would be really helpful if there is any documentation in PHP for the new or old versions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I see that the login path has changed compared to previous versions. **api/account/login**

```
$post = [
    'username' => 'Username',
    'key' => 'key',
];

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/index.php?route=api/account/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Ontrable I tried that and I get the same response :(